# I want to find the longest varchar in a specific column of a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's an example:

```
ID = INT IDENTITY
DESC = VARCHAR(5000)

ID | Desc
---|-----
1  | a
2  | aaa
3  | aa
```

The SQL query here should return `3` and the word itself i.e., `aaa`? Since the longest value is `aaa` with `3` characters?

The output should be:

```
aaa 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `order by` and limit the results to one row:

```
select description, len(description)
from t
order by len(description) desc
offset 0 row fetch first 1 row only;
```

Or use:

```
select top (1) description, len(description)
from t
order by len(description) desc;
```

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, this will first result in an error because the offset part is missing a keyword rows , then it should be offset 0 rows because this will return `aa | 2`. Cheers!

Comment: What do you know? The `offset 0 fetch first 1 row only;` clause works on Oracle. Thanks.

Comment: @VBoka . . . Every time I use `fetch` in SQL Server I have a block because of the requirement for the `offset` clause.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff , you are welcome. This things happen.

Comment: Hi @user1683793 I am not sure if I am following you.... I have tried without keyword rows in Oracle and no luck: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e5ca97ca84ba6c004abcc4bfbba7aaa8

Comment: @VBoka  It works on my Oracle 12.2 but not on my Oracle 11.2.  Since 11.2 is Production and 12.2 is something I have been testing on my own, I don't think I'll be using this construct any time soon.

Answer (score 3):

**With OFFSET & FETCH:**

- OFFSET is specifying how many rows from the top of the result set you will ignore ...
- And then the FETCH is used to limit the result to the number of rows you specify.

The combination of this two will return the desired result because the result set is ordered by len(descr).

```
select descr, len(descr)
from test
order by len(descr) desc
OFFSET 0 ROWS 
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

**With TOP:**

TOP will limit the reultset to the number of rows you specify. In this example 1. Because it is ordered by the lenght of the column *desc* then the first row will be the one you are looking for.

```
select top 1 descr, len(descr)
from test
order by len(descr) desc
```

[HERE IS A DEMO for both examples](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a1edd6b229b83075db99aeafd0f52a09)

**Note for the end:**

*Use aliases* (I will demonstrate on one of this two examples)

```
select descr as Description, len(descr) "Description length"
    from test
    order by len(descr) desc
    OFFSET 0 ROWS 
    fetch first 1 rows only;
```

You can put them between double quotes or not, use keyword `as` or not, it is up to you but the result looks better with them.

Both `ROW` and `ROWS` keyword is ok for OFFSET and FETCH clause. So what ever you want to use you can...

Answer (score 2):

You can try TOP as shown below. Here is the official documentation of [TOP (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
Select 
      top 1 Id, description, len(description) as MaxLength
from YourTable order by len(description) desc
```

[image]

[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d20974956baffefc1d88efe1760756ec)

Comment: Hi @SurajKumar , the OP is looking for the length and not the id. Check the example data again... Cheers!

Comment: @VBoka I have added that also.

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you want on Oracle (one of the tags on the question):

```
SELECT descript,length(descript)
FROM t WHERE length(descript)=( SELECT max(length(descript)) FROM t);
```

Keep in mind that if there are two (or more) records with that length, you will get them all.  You could add a `AND rownum < 2` clause but that will give you which ever entry the database chooses to give.

If you want the first record of those with the longest field, a subquery will be required:

```
SELECT descript,length(descript) from (
     select descript from t order by length(descript) desc, descript asc)
WHERE rownum < 2;
```

There is also the `offset 0 row fetch...` version listed earlier:

```
SQL> select descript, length(descript)
  2  from t
  3  order by length(descript) desc
  4  offset 0 row fetch first 1 row only;

DESCRIPT         LENGTH(DESCRIPT)
-------------------- ----------------
defg                    4
```

Mind you, this only works on my "12.2.0.1.0" Oracle.  If I try the same thing on my "11.2.0.4.0" Oracle, I get "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"   with that last line.  Apparently this is newer, maybe that is why I have never seen it before.

Comment: Hi @user1683793 in SQL Server it is `len` not `length`. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @user1683793 sorry, was not aware that at the beginning of the question there was a ORACLE tag. Cheers!